# Clarification about using Google ServerAuthCode

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I'm working with a legacy code that implements `Google SignIn`. Sign in flow follows like this:

1. Client authorizes to google account and requests serverAuthCode, Just like in [Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access)
2. `serverAuthCode` is used like an `AccessToken` for requests to get data from server. (e.g. `Authorization: bearer [serverAuthCode]`)
3. After 1 hour `serverAuthCode` gets expired on server and unauthorized exception is returned.

If I understood the official guide correctly `serverAuthCode` is used to grant the server permission to "communicate" with google instead of client while client is offline and it should not be used as `AccessToken`, right?

Problem I'm facing by this implementation is that I can't find any way to refresh `serverAuthCode`, I get the same code if I sign out and sign in with another user. Even clearing app data isn't helping. Only way is to re-install the app.

So is it "fine" to implement google auth like this and if yes, how do I refresh the serverAuthCode? 
Or should I just ask them to change the api according to documentation?

Comment: you want to refresh the server auth code that your server gives you or the Google AccessToken?

Comment: I want to refresh serverAuthCode

Comment: so send another request to the server

Comment: it returns the same code